# What is the Rails part in an hybrid Rails+Ember App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ember.js

Since we use ember's CRUD in an hybrid, what is Rails used for?
Validation's on ember side, routing in ember side, CRUD in ember side.

What is Rails have to do with all this?
Why do people couple them?
And lastly, is there any framework that will let me keep the logic in rails and will only take care of the views ?

Answer (score 0):

Rails takes care of the server side of the ember.js application like any other server side languages basically the rest API , Its not neccessary it has to be in rails , For Eg, We have used Ember.js with PHP and Java as well.

Comment: Well, i am already familiar with rails, heard ember makes good pair, but i think ember gets all the logic from rails, and implements its own.In this case, what is the need for a back-end api?

Comment: If you want to save it to a DB then you will need a backend api right ?

Comment: Thanks.It kinda makes sense.I can use rails valiations right? And one more question.Can i use gems like devise?

Comment: Of course you can , There are several libraries available for that like https://github.com/givanse/ember-cli-simple-auth-devise